# expression engine - count tag only counts from 1

Tags: php, javascript, count, expressionengine

I have a javascript sound player that plays items from a website based on a data-count attribute in the dom elements. That data-count attribute is incremented in each dom element element using expression engine's {count} tag. The problem is, {count} is indexed starting at 1, I need it to be indexed starting from 0. Anyone have any ideas on how to remedy this short of using PHP inside my templates to subtract 1 from the count variable before assigning it to the DOM element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I need it to spit out the proper number in the initial parsing stage, I developed a plugin for this. If you have this issue, you can download the plugin here:

http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mh-index

Answer (score 0):

Every time you reference count (in javascript-player), you could subtract 1. IE: `var c=count-1;`
Would that work for you?

See [this post](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewreply/973055/) on expressionengine.com for a solution to the same problem as yours.

Good luck!